# How to install/add packages from github to rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to learn how to install/add packages (if that's the correct term) into my rails application.  Specifically https://github.com/codegram/ember-forms.  I can't seem to find any tutorials or step by steps on how to do something like this, and don't recognize the folder/file structure for ember-forms.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just a Javascript library - build it using the supplied rake tasks or download the released version from the [downloads](https://github.com/codegram/ember-forms/downloads) page.

Unless you want to work on the library itself all you need are the generated javascript - pop it in vendor/assets/javascripts

Comment: Thanks for the response!  So I just need to add "ember-forms.js" to "vendor/assets/javascripts"?

Comment: Yup, that should do it. Then require it from application.js